# What is the correct phrase to describe an ongoing study for a PhD?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

She is doing a PhD in the X program at Y University,

She is working towards a PhD in the X program at Y University,

or

She is studying for a PhD in the X program at Y University.

Comment: I've heard all three. How formal is the context?

Comment: PhD is a combination of work and study so I’d go with *doing* or *getting.*

Comment: It will be used in a formal context, on a university website or in anewsletter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is actually a grammar question, as all of the choices follow the same grammatical structure. However, based on word choice, I would select your second option of:

> She is working towards a Ph.D. in the ~~ program at ~~ University.

An alternative way to refer to a Ph.D. is a Doctorate degree, and as such the colloquialism changes to:

> She is doing her Doctorate (degree) in (the) ~~ (program) at ~~ University.

Using the verb *doing* instead of saying *working toward* for this colloquialism is acceptable. Meaning, a sentence like this makes perfect sense:

> She is doing her Doctorate in Computer Science at Caltech.

or as you describe above:

> She is working towards a Ph.D. in Computer Science at Caltech.

Comment: You wouldn't capitalize "Doctorate" in this case as it isn't the actual name of the degree.